# How to configure an SSH jump server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

Using a Linux system, I want to download a file from a Windows server. However, I want to use a Raspberry Pi in between to act as a Jump Server.

**Linux client (A)------> Pi-jump server(B)---------->Windows Server (C)**

I want to send a request from A to C through B because I want C to get B IP address and not A's one. Also, I want C to reply sending back a file.

Therefore, I want to do:

```
tftp -g -t i -f $PATH_FILE $RASPBERRY_PI_IP
```

How do I need to configure the Pi so when I do that, I get the file from the server?

I found this command and run it in the Linux client:

```
ssh -L 8999:WINDOWS_SERVER_IP:8999 pi@RASPBERRY_PI_IP
```

However, what this does it's to log me in the Pi from the Linux client and what I want to do is just to send the command to download the file.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want the file to land up on the Pi or your computer? Also why do you want to do this? (The answer depends on the purpose and could range from you can't, to use SSH this way to use a VPN, proxy or NAT!)

Comment: @davidgo just edited my question. I hope it's clearer now. thanks! :)

Comment: The ssh command is correct: it will log you in to the raspberry, but until you logout you'll have a tunnel established to the Windows server. Point your tftp to localhost instead of the raspberry ip. Why port 8999 though? I thought tftp uses port 69.

Comment: @simlev I've just used a random port that I thought it wouldn't be blocked by the router or anything. Also, if I use port 69, 22 or even 21, I get this message: "Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root." I'm running as Administrator, so I'm not sure what to do there. Thanks!

Comment: I mean the remote port `:8999`, which should be the port where the tftp server is listening on.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario:**

You have a `remoteserver (C)` running a service on port `remoteport`. You want to connect to it, but your local machine `(A)` is blocked for whatever reason from reaching `remoteserver (C)` on `remoteport`. Luckily, you have ssh access to `tunnelserver (B)`, and from there it's possible to reach `remoteport` on `remoteserver (C)`. Therefore you come up with the bright idea of using `tunnelserver (B)` as a *jump server*: an intermediate hop to `remoteserver (C)` and `remoteport`.

```
localserver (A) -> tunnelserver (B) -> remoteserver (C)
```

---

Once the tunnel is established, you will connect to `localserver` on port `localport`, and passing through `tunnelserver` on `sshport` you'll will finally reach `remoteserver` on `remoteport`.

```
A:localport -> B:sshport -> C:remoteport
```

---

**Solution:**

Here's how to create an SSH tunnel:

```
 ssh -L <localport>:<remotehost>:<remoteport> -p <tunnelport> <tunneluser>@<tunnelserver>
```

This will log you in to `tunnelserver` with user `tunneluser`; the tunnel will die when you logout.

**Filling in port numbers:**

`localport` will be the port you connect to on the local machine: **choose any free TCP port**, i.e. a port where there's not already some local service running. You'll know if you have e.g. a webserver on your local machine and will therefore avoid ports `80` and `443`. On Linux systems ports `1` to `1023` are privileged by default, meaning that only the user `root` can bind a service there (prepend your command with `sudo` to overcome this if you are not `root` already).

`remoteport` is the port the remote service on `remotehost` is listening on. Most services have a default port (for `tftp` it is `69`), if you changed that you will know.

`sshport` is the ssh service port on `tunnelserver`: if you didn't change it from the default value it'll be `22` and you can omit the `-p <tunnelport>` parameter completely.

**Running it all:**

Let's say you choose local port `8999`, can ssh to `tunnelserver` via the usual `22`, and your remote tftp service is also on the default port `69`.

```
ssh -L 8999:<remotehost>:69 <tunneluser>@<tunnelserver>
```

You'll then connect to the remote tftp service through `localhost` on port `8999`:

```
tftp localhost 8999
```

Comment: this is really well explained! Thanks a lot. I just have one issue: temporary, I need to use SFTP instead of TFTP, so the port should be 22. So i follow all the steps you mentioned but instead of 69, I use 22. However, when I do "sftp localhost 8999", I login my actual localhost (A) instead of (C). Do you know what I could be missing?

Comment: @Natiya In that case, I'd check che IP addesses, and particularly that of the remote host.